# Create user group using RBAC API?

Tags: kubernetes, rbac, kubectl

I can't find documentation on how to create user group on Kubernetes with `yaml` file. I'd like gather some authenticated users in group using their e-mail accounts.

I'd like to write in `yaml` something like :

```
 kind: GoupBinding
 apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1
 metadata:
   name: "frontend-developers"
   namespace: development
subjects:
- kind: User
  name: a@xyz.com,vv@xyz.com
  apiGroup: ""
```

Answer (score 10):

Groups are determined by the configured authentication method. See https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/authentication/ for details about how each authenticator determines the group membership of the authenticated user.

Comment: Thanks ! I'd like to create a group of already authenticated users , to use such group when creating roles and roles-bindings . Still have no clue how to do it.

Comment: the identity provider will return the group a user belongs to... groups don't exist, they are a property of a user

Comment: @VincentDeSmet Does this means that users created through [Google API Console](https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials) (configured as shown [here](https://jtway.co/kubernetes-auth-google-with-rbac-60a74787e6a5)) cannot have any groups?

Comment: `oidc` requires to specify groups claim , the kube apiserver has the `--oidc-groups-claim` flag to provide the name of a custom OpenID Connect claim for specifying user groups. The claim value is expected to be a string or array of strings. and `--oidc-groups-prefix` to prefix all groups and prevent conflicts with other authentication strategies.