# How are Kubernetes user tokens authorized?

Tags: kubernetes, rbac

I have two kubernetes clusters that were set up by kops.  They are both running `v1.10.8`.  I have done by best to mirror the configuration between the two.  They both have RBAC enabled.  I have kubernetes-dashboard running on both.  They both have a `/srv/kubernetes/known_tokens.csv` with an `admin` and a `kube` user:

`$ sudo cat /srv/kubernetes/known_tokens.csv
ABCD,admin,admin,system:masters
DEFG,kube,kube
(... other users ...)`

My question is how do these users get authorized with consideration to RBAC?  When authenticating to kubernetes-dashboard using tokens, the `admin` user's token works on both clusters and has full access.  But the `kube` user's token only has access on one of the clusters.  On one cluster, I get the following errors in the dashboard.

`configmaps is forbidden: User "kube" cannot list configmaps in the namespace "default"
persistentvolumeclaims is forbidden: User "kube" cannot list persistentvolumeclaims in the namespace "default"
secrets is forbidden: User "kube" cannot list secrets in the namespace "default"
services is forbidden: User "kube" cannot list services in the namespace "default"
ingresses.extensions is forbidden: User "kube" cannot list ingresses.extensions in the namespace "default"
daemonsets.apps is forbidden: User "kube" cannot list daemonsets.apps in the namespace "default"
pods is forbidden: User "kube" cannot list pods in the namespace "default"
events is forbidden: User "kube" cannot list events in the namespace "default"
deployments.apps is forbidden: User "kube" cannot list deployments.apps in the namespace "default"
replicasets.apps is forbidden: User "kube" cannot list replicasets.apps in the namespace "default"
jobs.batch is forbidden: User "kube" cannot list jobs.batch in the namespace "default"
cronjobs.batch is forbidden: User "kube" cannot list cronjobs.batch in the namespace "default"
replicationcontrollers is forbidden: User "kube" cannot list replicationcontrollers in the namespace "default"
statefulsets.apps is forbidden: User "kube" cannot list statefulsets.apps in the namespace "default"`

As per the [official docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/authentication/#users-in-kubernetes), "Kubernetes does not have objects which represent normal user accounts".

I can't find anywhere on the working cluster that would give authorization to `kube`.  Likewise, I can't find anything that would restrict `kube` on the other cluster.  I've checked all `ClusterRoleBinding` resources in the `default` and `kube-system` namespace.  None of these reference the `kube` user.  So why the discrepancy in access to the dashboard and how can I adjust it?

Some other questions:

- How do I debug authorization issues such as this?  The dashboard logs just say this user doesn't have access.  Is there somewhere I can see which `serviceAccount` a particular request or token is mapped to?
- What are `groups` in k8s?  The [k8s docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/authentication/) mention groups a lot. Even the static token users can be assigned a group such as `system:masters which looks like a`role`/`clusterrole`but there is no`system:masters`role in my cluster?  What exactly are`groups`?  As per [Create user group using RBAC API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44763590/create-user-group-using-rbac-api), it appears groups are simply arbitrary labels that can be defined per user.  What's the point of them?  Can I map a group to a RBAC serviceAccount?

**Update**

I restarted the working cluster and it no longer works.  I get the same authorization errors as the working cluster.  Looks like it was some sort of cached access.  Sorry for the bogus question.  I'm still curious on my follow-up questions but they can be made into separate questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hard to tell without access to the cluster, but my guess is that you have a `Role` and a `RoleBinding` somewhere for the `kube` user on the cluster that works. Not a `ClusterRole` with `ClusterRoleBinding`.

Something like this:

```
kind: Role
metadata:
  name: my-role
  namespace: default
rules:
- apiGroups: [""]
  Resources: ["services", "endpoints", "pods"]
  verbs: ["get", "list", "watch"]
---
kind: RoleBinding
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1
metadata:
  name: kube-role-binding
  namespace: default
subjects:
- kind: User
  name: "kube"
  apiGroup: ""
roleRef:
  kind: Role
  name: my-role
  apiGroup: ""
```

> How do I debug authorization issues such as this? The dashboard logs
>   just say this user doesn't have access. Is there somewhere I can see
>   which serviceAccount a particular request or token is mapped to?

You can look at the kube-apiserver logs under `/var/log/kube-apiserver.log` on your leader master. Or if it's running in a container `docker logs <container-id-of-kube-apiserver>`

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I looked at `Role` and `RoleBinding` on the working cluster in the `default` and `kube-system` namespaces and there really is no reference to the `kube` user.  There is a `kubelet` reference in ClusterRoleBinding but unless there is some mapping between `kube" and `kubelet`, that wouldn't apply.

I also looked at /var/log/kube-apiserver.log but it doesn't help much.  I'll update the question with the output.

Comment: See update in the original issue.  Thanks for your help!